# Strip shortcode from excerpt while keeping excerpt length

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, shortcode

I have a lengthy shortcode at the start of some of my posts so when I use the `get_excerpt` function, the shortcode is printed out.

I would like to remove the shortcode from the excerpt but still have a full excerpt from the remaining post content.

For example if I have a `get_excerpt('150')` but my shortcode is over 150 characters long, then the stripped excerpt contains no content and is blank.

I've tried getting the post content, stripping the shortcodes, then trimming to 150 characters but that includes all the formatting from the post and includes photos and media which I do not want. I just want 150 characters of unformulated text from the post excluding the shortcodes.

I'm not interested in executing my shortcode in the post content.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Personally,  I no longer use Wordpress for years and I can't test anything. Perhaps your question is better fitted for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit more searching and trial and error I came up with this that resolves my issue.

```
function filter_shortcodes_from_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    $excerpt = wp_trim_words(strip_shortcodes(get_the_content(), 40 ));
    return $excerpt;    
}

add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'filter_shortcodes_from_excerpt' );
```